# Citrix Secure Gateway not redirecting to login URL

Tags: citrix, 503-error

We have an older setup for XenApp - users log in through Citrix Secure Gateway running on a windows box.  (We hope to start using a NetScaler soon.)

Earlier today, connections to https://citrix.company.com/ starting throwing up a 503 error page, instead of redirecting to https://citrix.company.com/Citrix/XenApp/  If you go directly to the /Citrix/Xenapp/ URL, the user is properly directed to the login page, and can launch apps.

We've restarted the service, and rebooted the server.  We haven't yet tried uninstalling and reinstalling the software.  Before we do this, I'm looking for ideas as to how we can get the redirect working again without a fairly major outage window.

To make things more interesting, many of our users have Citrix Receiver installed, also pointed at https://citrix.company.com/.  Receiver makes itself the default launcher for ICA files, and gives a connection error when it tries to load apps - probably because of the same non-functional rediect?

Comment: Just need to clarify if you're using the Access Gateway or the Secure Gateway - they are two different products and will impact what you need to look at.

Comment: The MMC snap-in for it calls it "Secure Gateway 3.3"

Comment: Also, have you definitely narrowed this down to CSG vs Web Interface. What happens if you try it on port 80 with http. I believe the redirect is actually there rather than with CSG. You may need to reconfigure the default site.

Comment: +1 to Dan. Generlaly, with CSG, the redirects are done on the web interface side.

Comment: Connecting directly to the web interface also yields the 503, but works if the /Citrix/XenApp/ path is specifically entered.  I will investigate further.

Comment: Yep, the DefaultAppPool for the web interface wasn't running, and would not start.  Rebooting the server in question fixed the issue.  Dan, if you want to post an actual answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirect from the root to the Citrix site is performed on Web Interface server, rather than through the Secure Gateway. You should check the Web Interface directly, bypassing CSG.